# Android: Move FloatingActionButton when onLongClick() is called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, floating-action-button

I have the following fragment with `CardView` and a `FloatingActionButton` from `TabbedActivity` created with support libraries:

[image]

Every card contains an `ImageView` with a heart, and for the last card in my fragment the `FloatingActionButton` covers the heart.

**Question:** How can I move the button anywhere I want when `onLongClick()` is called?

Another solution would be to move the button up when the end of the list is reached. But I would like to move the button anywhere I want on long press.

**Update 1:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    ...>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ...>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        .../>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    ..../>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:onClick="goToCamera"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please give your layout

Comment: What do you you mean by "anywhere I want"?

Comment: @BartoszLipinski Like the facebook floating button when you chat with someone and messenger app is not oppened. In my case I want to move it just in that fragment/activity.

Comment: hi. instead move it to anywhare then you can hide it when meet last item and show it when not by call show() and hide() method of float button.

Comment: @Sunny I added the layout in Update 1.

Comment: @GiapLee This is a solution but it would be more flexible to move it wherever you want.

Comment: so if you still want move it anywhere then you must move button into framelayout or any other which allow view easy move by cordinate (x,y)

Answer (score 2):

Set OnTouchListener inside OnLongClickListener:

```
fab.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setX(event.getRawX() - 120);
                            view.setY(event.getRawY() - 425);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
```

ACTION_DOWN is unnecessary here.
In ACTION_MOVE set X and Y coordinates. Coefficients 120 and 425 are picked empirically for Samsung S7 edge and might need other values in case of devices with different display size.
In case of ACTION_UP set OnTouchListener to null to stop tracking drag movements. That way another long click will be needed to start dragging FAB again.